# Query polymorphic relation table

Tags: mysql, eav

I'm trying to query the following table:

```
+----+------------------+----------------+-------------+-------+
| id | describable_type | describable_id | property_id | value |
+----+------------------+----------------+-------------+-------+
|  1 | product          |              1 |           6 | Red   |
|  2 | product          |              2 |           6 | Blue  |
|  3 | product          |              1 |           4 | 150   |
|  4 | product          |              2 |           4 | 150   |
+----+------------------+----------------+-------------+-------+
```

I want all `describable_id` where the value of property_id 6 is `Red` and property_id 4 is `150`.

I just cannot figure out how to query this.

Comment: This looks like an Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) design.  You can add some fancy name to it, but it is still an EAV undern the hood.  These designs are (99% of the time) BAD IDEAS.  https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/

Comment: It is a performance hit to have the `id` column.  Get rid of it and provide a suitable composite `PRIMARY KEY`.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta and http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT describable_id
FROM table
WHERE (property_id, value) IN ((6, 'Red'), (4, '150'))
GROUP BY describable_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT property_id, value) = 2
```

For strongly 2 pairs

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.describable_id
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 ON t1.describable_id = t2.describable_id
WHERE t1.property_id = 6
  AND t1.value = 'Red'
  AND t1.property_id = 4
  AND t1.value = '150'
```

If (property_id, value) is unique (by index!) you may remove DISTINCT from both queries.